# Launch and forget a dialog in Android causes a crash

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app which registers dialog and doesn't store a reference to it. I also add a dismiss handler:

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener { dialog -> /* Do something with a dialog */ }
```

Randomly I got this exception when dialog is closed:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: dialog must not be null
```

Consider this code in Dialog.java:

```
private static final class ListenersHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<DialogInterface> mDialog;

    public ListenersHandler(Dialog dialog) {
        mDialog = new WeakReference<>(dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case DISMISS:
                ((OnDismissListener) msg.obj).onDismiss(mDialog.get());
                break;
            case CANCEL:
                ((OnCancelListener) msg.obj).onCancel(mDialog.get());
                break;
            case SHOW:
                ((OnShowListener) msg.obj).onShow(mDialog.get());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's OnDismissListener for reference:

```
interface OnDismissListener {
    /**
     * This method will be invoked when the dialog is dismissed.
     *
     * @param dialog the dialog that was dismissed will be passed into the
     *               method
     */
    void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog);
}
```

WeakReference can be null if I don't store any references. It looks like that OnDismissListener in this case should be marked as @Nullable. Is is a bug in platform or am I missing something?

Comment: I believe it is Nullable. You should probably use `{ dialog -> /* Do something with dialog?.XXX */ }`

Comment: `"registers dialog and doesn't store a reference to it"`, and you are using `WeakReference`, which by nature makes your object available for the next upcoming GC event, without an object you can't store state and even just 'registering' these interfaces they are not going to help you save states.

Comment: Well not "me". It's the code from Android Platform SDK. I just don't understand why they put WeakReference there resulting in nullable parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when `onDismiss` invoked in here

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener { dialog -> /* Do something with a dialog */ }
```

your `dialog` can be null , 
you cannot use it in this line 
`/* Do something with a dialog */` .

you can add null check here ,

or better solution is keep reference of dialog and remove all listeners when you need.

Comment: Well yes I understand that. I believe this is a design flaw from Google here. This behavior is not properly stated anywhere.